# Flutter Widget Visibility

Tags: flutter

i have created PageViewBuilder to display my list items... and when i reach to the last item of the list...i want to show a hidden widget
how to implement that ?

this is the widget i want to show when i reach to the last item of the list

```
Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,width: 40,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      child: MaterialButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text('Done',style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.white
                      ),),)),
```

here is my full code

```
class _getPlanExDetails2ScreenState extends State<getPlanExDetails2Screen> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<LifeStyleCubit,LifeStates>(
      listener: (context,state)
      {},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        var cubit = LifeStyleCubit.get(context);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text('Exercise'),
          ),
          body: PageView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,index) => letsTest(cubit.PlanDaysExList[index],context,index),
            itemCount: cubit.PlanDaysExList.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: widget.pageController,
            ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20,right: 75,left: 75 ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,width: 40,
                      child: MaterialButton(onPressed: ()
                      {
                        widget.pageController.previousPage(duration:Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                      },child: Icon(IconBroken.Arrow___Left_2
                      ,color: Colors.white,),)),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,width: 40,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      child: MaterialButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text('Done',style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.white
                      ),),)),   // i need to show this widget when i reach to the last index of the list
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,width: 20,
                      child: MaterialButton(onPressed: ()
                      {
                        widget.pageController.nextPage(duration:Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                      },child: Icon(IconBroken.Arrow___Right_2
                      ,color: Colors.white,),)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

i tried to wrap it with Visiblity widget and use setState but i failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should **set an if statement** about last question and put **`visibile: true;`** for it.

While you dont want it to make visible for other questions, *you should put **visible: false;** inside your expanded widget.*

I hope it will help your problem.
Have nice coding time!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).